# Conversion from 3D cell array to a set of 2D matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a 3D-cell array designated as `A{s,i,h}`, serving as a store for large amounts of numerical data during a nested-loop portion of my script. Some of the cell entries will be blank `[ ]`, whilst the rest consist of numbers - either singular or in arrays (1 x 10 double etc.):

[image]

I want to convert this cell array to a set of 2D matrices.

Specifically, one separate matrix for each value of `h` (h is always equal `1:3`) and one column in each matrix for every value of `s`. Each column will contain all the numerical data combined - it does not need to be separated by `i`.

How can I go about this? I ordinarily deal with 3D-cell arrays in this form to produce separate matrices (one for each value of h) using something like this:

```
lens = sum(cellfun('length',reshape(A,[],size(A,3))),1);
max_length = max(lens);
mat = zeros(max_length,numel(lens));
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:max_length]',lens);
mat(mask) = [A{:}];
mat(mat==0) = NaN;
mat = sort(mat*100);
Matrix1 = mat(~isnan(mat(:,1)),1);
Matrix2 = mat(~isnan(mat(:,2)),2);
Matrix3 = mat(~isnan(mat(:,3)),3);
```

However in this instance, each matrix had only a single column. I'm have trouble adding multiple columns to each output matrix.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all columns of your output matrix will have the same length? Or do you need to define a fill value?

Comment: It's guaranteed that they will not be the same length - so a fill is required.

Comment: Also, are your grouping indices `h` and `m` or `i` and `m`? Please edit the answer, as it says `h` and `m`, and then  `i` and `m`

Comment: Updated. h will always equal `1:3` - so the number of output matrices requires is always 3. `m` however will be variable.

Comment: Can ask the obvious question?  If `i` and `j` are ignored then why create them in the first place?  This appears to be some kind of looping operation where the easy answer is remove the useless structures.  If you eliminate `i` and `j` the output would be a cell of 3 matrices exactly as you want.

Comment: "Ignore" may be an incorrect description. They are only ignored as far as separating the data into columns/matrices. During the nested loop structure, functions are carried out during each iteration of `j` (`1:16`). These 16 iterations are then repeated x number of times (`i`). I've been storing the results obtained from each iteration of j. I could potentially remove this, but I do not know a way to store the results without them being overwritten during every iteration of `j`.

Comment: If you are using only `A(:,1,1,1:3)` to store the results then reduce the size of `A` to `A(:,1:3)` and store the intermediates somewhere else.  You can easily create another cell say `B` of size `B(i,j,h)` to hold the other values, if they don't depend on `h` then just `B(i,j)`.  You would still index into `A` the same way.  It sounds like `A(:,2:end,2:end,:)` are useless once your script is done.  If that is true don't keep them in the output.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a more sensible approach. I will give it a go.

Comment: What are the contents of each cell? You say they may be empty. I assume a cell can also contain a number. Can it contain a row vector too? A column vector? A matrix?

Comment: Row vectors, column vectors, or both?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect a simplification of the problem - removing the fourth dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Result in the form of a cell array of matrices (as requested)

Here's one possible approach. I had to use one `for` loop. However, the loop can be easily avoided if you accept a 3D-array result instead of a cell array of 2D-arrays. See second part of the answer.

If you follow the comments in the code and inspect the result of each step, it's straightforward to see how it works.

```
%// Example data
A(:,:,1) = { 1:2, 3:5, 6:9; 10 11:12 13:15 };
A(:,:,2) = { 16:18, 19:22, 23; 24:28, [], 29:30 };

%// Let's go
[S, I, H] = size(A);
B = permute(A, [2 1 3]); %// permute rows and columns
B = squeeze(mat2cell(B, I, ones(1, S), ones(1, H))); %// group each col of B into a cell...
B = cellfun(@(x) [x{:}], B, 'uniformoutput', false); %// ...containing a single vector
t = cellfun(@numel, B); %// lengths of all columns of result
result = cell(1,H); %// preallocate
for h = 1:H
    mask = bsxfun(@le, (1:max(t(:,h))), t(:,h)).'; %'// values of result{h} to be used
    result{h} = NaN(size(mask)); %// unused values will be NaN
    result{h}(mask) = [B{:,h}]; %// fill values for matrix result{h}
end
```

Result in this example:

```
A{1,1,1} =
     1     2
A{2,1,1} =
    10
A{1,2,1} =
     3     4     5
A{2,2,1} =
    11    12
A{1,3,1} =
     6     7     8     9
A{2,3,1} =
    13    14    15
A{1,1,2} =
    16    17    18
A{2,1,2} =
    24    25    26    27    28
A{1,2,2} =
    19    20    21    22
A{2,2,2} =
     []
A{1,3,2} =
    23
A{2,3,2} =
    29    30

result{1} =
     1    10
     2    11
     3    12
     4    13
     5    14
     6    15
     7   NaN
     8   NaN
     9   NaN
result{2} =
    16    24
    17    25
    18    26
    19    27
    20    28
    21    29
    22    30
    23   NaN
```

## 2. Result in the form of 3D array

As indicated above, using a 3D array to store the result permits avoiding loops. In the code below, the last three lines replace the loop used in the first part of the answer. The rest of the code is the same.

```
%// Example data
A(:,:,1) = { 1:2, 3:5, 6:9; 10 11:12 13:15 };
A(:,:,2) = { 16:18, 19:22, 23; 24:28, [], 29:30 };

%// Let's go
[S, I, H] = size(A);
B = permute(A, [2 1 3]); %// permute rows and columns
B = squeeze(mat2cell(B, I, ones(1, S), ones(1, H))); %// group each col of B into a cell...
B = cellfun(@(x) [x{:}], B, 'uniformoutput', false); %// ...containing a single vector
t = cellfun(@numel, B); %// lengths of all columns of result
mask = bsxfun(@le, (1:max(t(:))).', permute(t, [3 1 2])); %'// values of result to be used
result = NaN(size(mask)); %// unused values will be NaN
result(mask) = [B{:}]; %// fill values
```

This gives (compare with result of the first part):

```
>> result
result(:,:,1) =
     1    10
     2    11
     3    12
     4    13
     5    14
     6    15
     7   NaN
     8   NaN
     9   NaN
result(:,:,2) =
    16    24
    17    25
    18    26
    19    27
    20    28
    21    29
    22    30
    23   NaN
   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force approach:

```
[num_s, num_i, num_h] = size(A);
cellofmat = cell(num_h,1);
for matrix = 1:num_h
    sizemat = max(cellfun(@numel, A(:,1,matrix)));
    cellofmat{matrix} = nan(sizemat, num_s);
    for column = 1:num_s
        lengthcol = length(A{column, 1, matrix});
        cellofmat{matrix}(1:lengthcol, column) = A{column, 1,matrix};
    end
end
Matrix1 = cellofmat{1};
Matrix2 = cellofmat{2};
Matrix3 = cellofmat{3};
```

I don't know what your actual structure looks like but this works for `A` that is setup using the following steps.

```
A = cell(20,1,3);
for x = 1:3
    for y = 1:20
        len = ceil(rand(1,1) * 10);
        A{y,1,x} = rand(len, 1);
    end
end
```

Comment: Edited to fix an error with the inner loop indexing.  Previously I used `num_h` instead of `matrix` so all 3 output matrices were the same.